# How to dim system bars on one click on the activity and again show system bars on the second click on the screen?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, statusbar, bottomnavigationview, android-immersive

Please Check the Images

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxdtM.png)

[Image 2 after one click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEftV.png)

I want to hide and show all system bars (status bar, Action Bar and Bottom Navigation Bar) in every clicks on the activity screen.

Answer (score 0):

On the first click set onClickListner that will lead to a new activity that only will display the image (ImageView) with a black background.
In the new activity make sure it is a full-screen activity:

Programmatically:

```
public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
       //Here display your image with an ImageView

       //Here set another onClickListner on the image or the background (the layout) that leads to the previous activity and finish() this one.
    }
}
```

Or in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

If it is AppCompatActivity

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```